# Is it bad practice to iterate over many random training & test set splits until a high accuracy is achieved?

Tags: python, machine-learning

Suppose I iterate with the following code until I acquire an accuracy that I'm satisfied with:

```
  from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

  x, y = # ... read in some data set ...
  c = 3000 # iterate over some arbitrary range
  for i in range(c):
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=i)

    model = # ... initialize some classifier of choice ...

    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    p = model.predict(x_test)
    p = np.round(p).reshape(-1)
    test_accuracy = np.mean(p == y_test) * 100
```

For a particular data set and range, say I build a classifier such that the training accuracy is 97% and the test accuracy is 96%. Can I truly claim the model is 96% accurate? For the same range and data set, I can also build a classifier such that the training accuracy and test accuracy are as low as 99% and 70%, respectively.

Since I have selected `random_state` based on the test set accuracy, is the test set really a validation set here? I don't know why, but I think to claim the first model is 96% accurate would not be true. What should I do instead in order to make a correct claim about the model's accuracy?

Comment: It seems like you have just re-invented [cross-validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) which is a perfectly valid tool to use, but worth reading about to implement correctly. Since stack overflow is more for specific coding questions rather than theory, this may be a better question for [stats.se] or [datascience.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it bad practice to iterate over many random training & test set splits until a high accuracy is achieved?

Yes, this is bad practice. You should be evaluating on data that your model has never been trained on, and this wouldn't really be the case if you train many times to find the best train/test split.

You can put aside a test set before you train the model. Then you can create as many train/validation splits as you want and train the model multiple times. You would evaluate on the test set, on which the model was never trained.

You can also look into [nested cross-validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html).

Comment: Regarding nested CV, does this sound correct: a single execution of K-fold cross-validation evaluates K models with identical hyperparameters. If there are L different combinations of hyperparameters, then finding optimal hyperparameters for the whole training set requires training K * L models. This constitutes the entirety of the inner loop. We do this M times, each with a different training/test set split (i.e. M folds, the outer loop). So after having trained K * L * M models, we have an average performance of both the hyperparameter selection process and a set of hyperparameters itself.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda. There is Cross-Validation which is similar to what you have described. This is where the train/test split is randomised and the model trained each time. Except the final value quoted is the average test accuracy - not simply the best. This sort of thing is done in tricky situations e.g. with very small datasets.

In terms of the bigger picture, the test data should be representative of the training data and vice versa. Sure you can cheese it that way, but if the atypical 'weird' cases are hidden in your training set and the test set is just full of easy cases (e.g. only the digit 0 for MNIST) then you aren't really achieving anything. You're only cheating yourself.